# Use lenskit framework recommender system in google ApEngine

Tags: google-app-engine, recommendation-engine, lenskit

Hy every one;

Can we use lenskit framework of recommender system in google AppEngin 
or can we use other recommender Engine

Thanks by Advance

Answer (score 0):

There should be no reason you can't use LensKit in Google AppEngine.  You will probably need to implement a data access backend that talks to your AppEngine storage, but most applications using LensKit implement a data access backend for their particular database anyway.